# How to remove duplicates in django /postgres while the primary key is a String

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

In the below table, id is my primary key , The item A with date 2021/07/22 is duplicated in the below , I want that to be removed. In short the combination of item and date should be unique

```
id     item        date        price
qwtywte  A       2021/07/22      102
afdsgfg  B       2021/07/22      210
hgasdah  A       2021/07/22      102
basjhjs  A       2021/07/21      114
vsjdsjg  B       2021/07/21      250
```

I am ok with solution from sql query or in django ORM query

Comment: `In short the combination of item and date should be unique` In your example data, this combination **is** unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things you need to do here.

1. Manually remove all the duplicate data. Even if you change the table definition Postgres isn't going to know which records are the ones you want to keep, so you're going to have to write something to sanitise your data yourself and remove the record you don't want.
2. Update the table definition so you don't get more invalid data in. You can do this with `unique_together`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together

Exactly how you do all this kind of depends on whether you can take the system down while you handle it all - if there's new data coming in all the time it will be more problematic.

Edit: Since you can take the system offline to do this, it's a lot easier than trying to deal with potential incoming problems ...

I was just starting to type out some SQL, then did a quick google and found this, which is pretty much what you want :)

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-in-postgresql/

Don't forget to add the new constraint and run migrations before you bring the system back online, or you'll just have to do it all again in the future!

Comment: Before applying unique_together ,I need a sql or django orm script to remove the existing duplicate recs . i am bit new to django and postgres , can you help me with the script ??

Comment: Yes, this was point 1 :) Question - can you kick off all users from the system while you do this? If you can't it's a a bit harder ...

Comment: I can do it it in off hrs, since the id is in  string , finding  difficult to remove the duplicates

Comment: I updated the answer and linked you a tutorial on removing dups in pg ...  I'd probably use that last method with the intermediate table myself, but go with whatever you find easiest ...